# Pass a counter to another activity Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Sorry my poor english

I am trying to increment an integer value in second activity when I click on a button in my first activity.
Firstly I click in some button. After that on my second activity, increments a number and should save to show in my TextView, using shared preferences.

But what I am trying to do is not working

```
  nao=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nao);
      nao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {



            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), BancoList.class);
            intent2.putExtra("num", 1);
```

Second Activity

```
 TextView tv;
SharedPreferences shre;
private int numero;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String text = shre.getString("image_data", "");

    if( !text.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
        tv.setText(text);
    }

Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent.getIntExtra("num", 1) == 1) {

        String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
        int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(present_value_string);
        present_value_int++;

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(present_value_int));

        shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=shre.edit();
        edit.putString("image_data", present_value_string);
        edit.commit();
```

My log cat, @nolly-j

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

                                                                                  Process: com.example.wolney.tabhost, PID: 31184
                                                                             java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to      java.lang.Integer
                                                                                      at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
                                                                                      at com.example.wolney.tabhost.fragments.FragmentUm$1.onClick(FragmentUm.java:50)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can the content of shared preferences be an int of does it have to be a string ?

Comment: @mikwee Yes. Could be an int. I tried already also

Comment: i'm not getting actually what you're trying to do. You're setting num in first activity `intent2.putExtra("num", 1);` and checking in second activity `if(intent.getIntExtra("num", 1) == 1) {` it'll always true. Then why `image_data` and `num` are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move to the second activity page and come back to the first activity, your counter variable might loss its initial value. Since you are using Shared Preference, it is better you set it once you click to move to the second activity page.

In the first activity page, do this

add class mamber

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
```

then in onCreate method, add

```
nao = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nao);
    nao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // retrieve the value of counter from Shared Preference
            preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            int counter = preferences.getInt("image_data", 0);
            counter++;

            // store the value of counter after incrementing it by 1
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
            edit.putInt("image_data", counter);
            edit.commit();

            // move to the second activity page
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), BancoList.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });
```

in the second activity page, use this code. In this case, you don't need to store your counter in intent

```
// in the second activity page, get the stored counter value
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int counter = preferences.getInt("image_data", 0);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

hope it helps

Comment: didnt work :( java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                                                                                at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
                                                                                at com.example.wolney.tabhost.fragments.FragmentUm$1.onClick(FragmentUm.java:53)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

Comment: sorry change this line in the click event method -  edit.putString("image_data", String.valueOf(currentCounter)); to  edit.putInt("image_data", String.valueOf(currentCounter));

Comment: this "currentCounter" I write just "counter", right? And I deleted "String.valueOf", because it had to be integer value. But it is not working yet :((

Comment: still having same error :( I don't know what could be wrong. But thanks anyway for your help. ~~~~~~ java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
                                                                                at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:240)
                                                                                at com.example.wolney.tabhost.fragments.FragmentUm$1.onClick(FragmentUm.java:54)

Comment: I think you should check where you are using String value instead of int value. Did you see all the edit I made in my code. I have tested it and it is working for me. Copy my code as it is and try it again.

Comment: I copied your code and didn't work. The only diference that i think don't have any problems is that i am using onCreateView instead of onCreate. I am working with fragments

Comment: Well, I don't understand why should not work. Can you see an line number that you error is point to your error log. You can upload your error log also

Comment: I posted my log cat. When I click (FragmentUm.java:50). This bring me to line:  int counter = preferences.getInt("image_data", 0);

Comment: Please delete the app and install a fresh copy.

Comment: Although you've got it going, I wonder if it might be more Androidy to return the value through startActivityForResult(), rather than using preferences. More at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html.